# How to created variable argumented pure virtual function in abstract class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

How to created variable argumented pure virtual function in abstract class? so that it can be used as per the created object?

requirement is I want to create one pure virtual function, which is used in many derived classes, and all the classes uses different number of argument for the same function

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47137318/edit).

Comment: what is a "variable argumented function" ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question in detail. Thanks

Comment: Sounds clear enough to me : a virtual function with variadic parameters. Unfortunately, that's not possible -- if every derived class has a different parameter list, you need to know the derived type to call the function, and thus the abstraction that `virtual` would've given you is useless.

Comment: That sounds more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than a requirement.